# Make MySQL default to utf8mb4

Tags: mysql

How does one make MySQL default to utf8mb4 for all strings, table types, and the connection encoding? I have this in my `my.cnf` file:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

Yet I still have `latin8` showing up in places.

Comment: What places are showing latin8? Did you create/populate tables before the change?

Comment: Column encoding overrides table encoding which overrides db encoding which overrides connection encoding.

Comment: Pretty much every time I create a new table, if a column in VARCHAR it shows up as `latin8`, and not `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection encoding can be overriden on per-session basis, and actually it is a good practice, so you need to check actual clients.

Keep eye on:

- Databases and tables have their own encoding, you need to convert them.
- in utf8mb4 maximum varchar length that fits in index is 191, not 255 as before, so transition is not just 'copy-paste-run'
- backup dumps contain pre-transition encoding
- some tools/migrations can contain old encoding

Comment: These are useful words of advice, but I'm still not sure why I keep ending up with `latin1` column types when the default is `utf8mb4` (or even `utf8`).  I'm using `utf8mb4` rather than `utf8` because I don't like Unicode outside of the BMP being regarded as invalid.